# Solution to send email from python

Tags: python, gmail

## this is the solution for sending gmail using python

import smtplib
    from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText

```
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = 'me@gmail.com'
msg['To'] = 'you@gmail.com'
msg['Subject'] = 'Hello'
message = 'This is mail from python.'
msg.attach(MIMEText(message))

mailserver = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
# identify ourselves to smtp gmail client
mailserver.ehlo()
# secure our email with tls encryption
mailserver.starttls()
# re-identify ourselves as an encrypted connection
mailserver.ehlo()
mailserver.login('me@gmail.com', 'password')

mailserver.sendmail('me@gmail.com','you@gmail.com',msg.as_string())

mailserver.quit()


# Note: You may have to change following settings
   # disable access protection. to do this right click mcafee virus then 
      #open 
   #virus scan control and right click access protection
   # in gmail allow less secure apps 
   #https://myaccount.google.com/security#connectedapps
```

Comment: Is it a solution or a question ??

Comment: this is solution...

Comment: I'm voting to close this "solution" as off-topic because Stackoverflow is for questions and answers, not for solutions. It should be posted in a question format first, and then the author can answer themselves if desired.